# Need AjaxCallDecorator to show up conditionally based on drop down value

Tags: wicket

I have a dropdown that I am using an AjaxCallDecorator on.  Currently, when you select an address from the drop down list, I use some ajax to run some checks on the address.  I use a spinner icon next to the drop down to let the user know that something is happening.  One of the options in the dropdown is "enter address manually".  When they select this, I do not want the AjaxCallDecorator to decorate.  It doesn't pop up for very long ( maybe a quarter of a second ) but I do not want it to appear at all.

I can not figure out how to have the Decorator appear conditionally based on what the user has selected in the drop down.  The getAjaxCallDecorator is only used to determine what decorator to use and I am pretty sure it is only called once, on initialize or page load.  It is not called everytime you select a new drop down choice.

Thanks.

( Sorry, should have included that I am using wicket 1.4.20 )

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The first solution that came to mind is to check what option was choosed by user directly in JavaScript code.

Here's code for Wicket 1.5 (since it's the last version with AjaxCallDecorator):

```
@Override
protected IAjaxCallDecorator getAjaxCallDecorator() {
    return new AjaxCallDecorator() {

        @Override
        public CharSequence decorateScript(Component c, CharSequence script) {
            return "if (" + shouldUseDecoratorScript() + ") { /* Show the spinner icon */ } " + script;
        }

        @Override
        public CharSequence decorateOnSuccessScript(Component c, CharSequence script) {
            return "if (" + shouldUseDecoratorScript() + ") { /* Hide the spinner icon */ } " + script;
        }

        @Override
        public CharSequence decorateOnFailureScript(Component c, CharSequence script) {
            return "if (" + shouldUseDecoratorScript() + ") { /* Hide the spinner icon */ } " + script;
        }

        private CharSequence shouldUseDecoratorScript() {
            return "this.value !== \"" + enterAddressManuallyItem.getId() + "\"";
        }
    };
}
```

Here enterAddressManuallyItem is the item that corresponds to "enter address manually" option. I assume that it has getId() getter, and you use something like

```
new ChoiceRenderer<DropDownChoiceItem>("text", "id")
```

as the last parameter of your DropDownChoice constructor.

Maybe, there's a better solution.